# SQL query to find average number of days between a customer's first and second purchase?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with below columns and need a query to find average number of days between a customer's first and second purchase.

Table name Customer_purchases:

customer_id| purchase_id| timestamp| amount

field_name| datatype| description

customer_id|int|unique id for each customer

purchase_id|int|unique id for each purchase

timestamp | datetime | timestamp of purchase

amount | float| amount customer paid for the purchase

Any suggestions ?

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: @Rubyuser Can you please provide sample data and what output you required and what have you tried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the first purchase [min(timestamp)] for each customer, then a join to a subquery getting the min(timestamp) where the timestamp > first one.

```
;with first_purchase as 
(
    select
        customer_id,
        min(timestamp) as DateOfFirstPurchase
    from
        Customer_purchases
    group by
        customer_id
) 
select
    first_purchase.customer_id,
    first_purchase.DateOfFirstPurchase,
    second_purchase.DateOfSecondPurchase,
    datediff(dd, first_puchase.DateOfFirstPurchase, second_purchase.DateOfSecondPurchase) as NumDaysBetween
from    
    first_purchase fp
    inner join
    (
        select
            cp2.customer_id,
            min(timestamp) as DateOfSecondPurchase
        from
            dbo.Customer_purchases cp2
            inner join first_purchase fp on cp2.customer_id = fp.customer_id
        where
            cp2.timstamp > fp.DateOfFirstPurchase
        group by
            cp2.customer_id
    ) second_purchase on fp.customer_id = second_purchase.customer_id
```

That would give you all the raw data, then average as you needed to.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to use DATEDIFF for Min and Max orderdate but not the first and second purchase or AVG of the DATEDIFF. I'm not a database developer and hence using online platforms for testing my query.